# How to get count and group by country in group by sql query

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table with data like this:

```
Id | Country | Desktop_User | Mobile_User
------------------------------------------
1  | USA     | True          | False
2  | Brazil  | False         |            
3  | Mexico  |               | True
4  | India   | True          | True
5  |         | False         | True
```

I would like a report type data where where I can get total counts for ALL "Desktop_User" TRUE and ALL "Mobile_User" TRUE group by country (considering that some records may have NULL value for country or Desktop_User or Mobile_User column. Something like this:

```
Country    | Desktop_User | Mobile_User
------------------------------------------
USA        | 100          | 49
China      | 50           | 10
India      | 11           | 5
Brazil     | 11           | 0
Mexico     | 0            | 0
NO COUNTRY | 5            | 7
```

I would like data sorted by country in alphabetical order - is it possible

So far I have created this query (below) but I think my logic is not correct around getting all TRUES for desktop and mobile users and NULL values

And what's the best way I can sort the data?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country    AS Country, 
       COUNT(Desktop_User) AS Desktop_User, 
       COUNT(Mobile_User)  AS Mobile_User
  FROM Contacts
 WHERE Desktop_User = 'True'
    OR Mobile_User  = 'True'
 GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT! Your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select Country AS Country
,      SUM(case when Desktop_User = 'True' then 1 else 0 end) as Desktop_User_cnt
,      SUM(case when Mobile_User = 'True' then 1 else 0 end) as Mobile_User_cnt
FROM   Contacts
WHERE  ((Desktop_User = 'True') OR (Mobile_User = 'True'))
group by Country
Order by Desktop_User_cnt desc
```

DISTINCT is unnecessary when you're grouping.

Comment: Add `else 0` to get sum 0 instead of null, for Brazil and Mexico.

Comment: Thank you @HoneyBadger and @jarih for your quick response. Just clarifying- so I do need `WHERE  ((Desktop_User = 'True') OR (Mobile_User = 'True'))` even when we are defining true condition within SUM?

Comment: I ran the above query and I have noticed something, when I run a query to see how many countries I have in the database, I get almost 100 countries (including a NULL row) with this query `SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM
Contacts` but when I run the above query that we are discussing, I get almost half countries like around 50. Which I am seeing this difference when we have the condition to consider null for all 3 columns. Shouldn't I get the exact same number of countries as the target is to list all possible countries their TRUE counts for desktop and mobile column in respect to each country?

Comment: If you want the total list of countries, you can remove the where clause. You should the same countries as with `SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Contacts`

Comment: That worked thank you @HoneyBadger What is the best way to sort the data? So, we have maximum counts at the top and lowest at the bottom?

Comment: The *only* way to sort the data is to use `order by`.

Comment: Be sure to accept this answer if it solved your problem. If you have more questions, I advise you to ask a new question, rather than expending on this question.

Comment: Hi @HoneyBadger I have accepted this answer - Thank you. I am trying to use ORDER by and it keeps throwing error. I am adding this at the end `ORDER BY COUNT(Desktop_User) DESC` and I have also tried this  `ORDER BY Country DESC` and `ORDER BY Desktop_User DESC`. Error - The ORDER BY clause is invalid

Comment: You can simply do something like `order by SUM(case when Desktop_User = 'True' then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: Just tried that and I get same error - `The ORDER BY clause is invalid unless TOP is specified`

Comment: You are probably using it in a subquery, you can't sort a subquery. If you have other questions, please post a new question.

Comment: I am basically doing this. `select Country AS Country
,      SUM(case when Desktop_User = 'True' then 1 else 0 end) as Desktop_User
,      SUM(case when Mobile_User = 'True' then 1 else 0 end) as Mobile_User
FROM   Contacts
WHERE  ((Desktop_User = 'True') OR (Mobile_User = 'True'))
group by Country
SUM(case when Desktop_User = 'True' then 1 else 0 end)` .Sure - I can create a new topic but I figured to ask here since I included sorting question in my question originally. In case someone else is looking for same solution, they can get answers at one place.

Comment: Hi @HoneyBadger - Just checking if you are waiting for me to create a new topic for this question? This question was in my original request in this topic.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I think you may have had a copy past error in your last query. The group by is wrong and there is no order by. I've edited my answer to show how to order, note I've changed the column alias.